# Windows Phone 8: Unable to add reference to System.Xml.Linq.dll

Tags: xml, linq, windows-phone-8

I am trying to parse an XML file for my Windows Phone 8 project. I want to use XDocument class. When I try to add the reference to System.Xml.Linq.dll, visual studio tells me "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project"

- Version of dll: 4.0.30319.18020
- Visual Studio Ultimate: 2013 with
  Windows Phone 8.0 SDK
- My dll lives in .Net folder: C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5

BTW, I tried creating regular c# console application on the same machine-visual studio version, but there System.xml and system.xml.dll are already added to a project by default.

Also, I searched online and looks like you can do 'unblock", but i don't see that option, probably because I don't have a zip file. http://pcmusings.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/vs2012-windows-phone-and-the-reference-to-a-higher-version-error/

I am surprise why it doesn't work for windows phone. Any pointers please?

Thank you!

Comment: Uou added using System.Xml.Linq; and you still cannot access the XDocument class?

Comment: looks like my VS got into a wired state. i recreated the project and copied over files and it resolved the issue.